# How to display two list Views in a Single Activity

Tags: android

Hi i am doing one project,I failed to display two listViews in a SingleActivity,
one list am getting from xml as product catalog other one contains Images(LazyImagelo ader)....  here i am not under
standing how i can get
can you help me to display  each product catalog and it's related image in a Single row of 
List..

Comment: Can you post your current source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Custom row in `ListView`, so you just have to use one `ListView` which you could use to display your category and your picture.

Comment: Yes, thanks longdm for spending time for me. I done this by takeing one more Linear Layout with Orientaion Horizental then it displayed in a Single Line.